# Ubuntu Installation -> HP 1000 - i3-2370M

Tags: hp

I have HP 1000 -  i3-2370M notebook. I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 but non of them gets installed. I have some success with 13.04 beta version.

Actually when I try to boot from Ubuntu, it starts but after few second screen become black and nothing happens. Then I tried with External LCD then I was able to see Ubuntu and it helped me to install Ubuntu. Once I installed Both Laptop LCD and External LCD show me desktop and I can work fine but when I remove external LCD and reboot Notebook then again it stuck on Black Screen even Ubuntu is installed and if again I add external LCD then i can work on Ubuntu.. But this process only work with 13.04 beta. 12.04 or 12.10. Does not work in any way. I tested 64 bit Ubuntu.

If have window 7 and tried to install ubuntu then i download ubuntu but when it extract then it give some error and install does not install anything.

Please look into this laptop and try to add in upcoming ubuntu 13.04. So i can use ubuntu.
Here is HP 1000 Notebook Specification:

HP 1000 Specifications:

```
Intel® Core™ i3-2370M Processor (2.4 GHz, 3MB L3 Cache)
Intel® HM75 Express Chipset
Intel® HD Graphics 3000
14.0-inch diagonal HD Bright View LED-Display (1366 x 768)
2GB DDR3 System Memory
HP 500GB 5400RPM Hard Disk Drive
HP SuperMulti DVD Writer
Integrated 10/100BASE-T Ethernet LAN 802.11b/g/n WLAN
3 USB 2.0, HDMI, RJ-45, Headphone out, Microphone in HP 720p High Definition Webcam with integrated microphone
Altec Lansing Internal Speakers
6-Cell Lithium-Ion Battery
HP 65W AC Adapter with Power Cable
Notebook keyboard with Touchpad supporting Multi-Touch
```

I will wait for positive feedback from ubuntu officials.

Comment: HP 1000 has Legacy BIOS mode. I think Ubuntu can be installed on UEFI BIOS Mode. If you have that then you can also install Ubuntu along-with Windows 8/8.1/10.

Answer (score 0):

You could install via:

- [LiveCD (Windows)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
- [(MAC) LiveCD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)
- [(Ubuntu) LiveCD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)

And you could install via USB.

- [USB (Windows)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [USB (MAC)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)
- [USB (Ubuntu)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)

Relese Notes:

- [12.10 Relese Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)
- [12.04 Relese Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)
- [12.10 Images and Checksums](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/)
- [12.04 Images and Checksums](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/)

I would reccomend 12.04. Have a little try before you install Ubuntu!

Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: No, non of them work. I have tried. all this... When i restart it.. It get stuck on black screen...

Comment: It is not being installed. I have tried.